# Magento2 : How to setup PWA in Localhost?

Tags: magento2.3, localhost, pwa

I want to setup `PWA` in localhost. I have tried in localhost but at last its giving dynamic staging server `URL` like below

```
https://magento-venia.local.pwadev:51828/
```

How can we change it to our localhost server `URL`.

Comment: Not getting the point, it is connected with your localhost. The url that you obtained is the url of development server, you can see your changes there

Answer (score 2):

alright you just need to update `.env` for variable `CUSTOM_ORIGIN_EXACT_DOMAIN`

```
 # vi .env
 # update value 
   CUSTOM_ORIGIN_EXACT_DOMAIN="pwa.dev"
 # now run 
   yarn buildpack create-custom-origin ./
 # Acquired custom hostname and SSL cert for pwa.dev. Development server will run on port 8626 and staging server will run on port 9626
 # Run server again
   yarn watch 
 # Project is running at https://pwa.dev:8626/
```

[Official pwa setup guide](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/pwa-studio-fundamentals/project-setup/) And [Create custom origin guide](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/pwa-buildpack/reference/buildpack-cli/create-custom-origin/)

let me know if this works

Answer (score 1):

If you checked the steps and results from PWA documentation: https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/ you will see that actually you got the local dev URL for your PWA development server. Check to add that URL to your `hosts` file in case that is not working for your setup.

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 2.3.1 PWA setup on local server**

Requirements:

Nodejs > 10.14.1 installed

yarn > 1.13.0 installed

A running instance of Magento 2.3.1 or above

**Steps to Setup PWA in local server**

- Clone the PWA studio repository in the development environment: git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git
- Install yarn from your pwa-studio root directory `yarn install`
- Create the .env file at location `pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept\` using following command

  MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/" yarn buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept
- Set the `MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL`. You can use the value provided in the example command or use your Magento instance url. This URL points to a cloud instance of Magento 2.3.1 with the Venia sample data installed.
- Generate SSL Certificate using `yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept`
- Build artifacts for Venia using the following command from the project root directory

  `yarn run build`
- Start the Venia development environment using the following command

  `yarn run watch:venia`
- You can browse your PWA Magneto application at `https://magento-venia-concept-j2188.local.pwadev:8119`

**Hope this solution will work for you.**

Comment: From where these URL's coming , please provide specific and detailed reply